# Are we able to use GitHub API to create a commit? especially v4?

Tags: github, github-api

Are we able to use GitHub API to create a commit? 
Can we use API to upload a file/blob, like what we can do using Git command, 
especially in API v4?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably yes, using the [GitHub Commits API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#create-a-commit) (in the context of a [GitHub application](https://developer.github.com/apps/))

You can see the all sequence in "[GitHub API Git Data](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/)":

- Get the current commit object
- Retrieve the tree it points to
- Retrieve the content of the blob object that tree has for that particular file path
- Change the content somehow and post a new blob object with that new content, getting a blob SHA back
- Post a new tree object with that file path pointer replaced with your new blob SHA getting a tree SHA back
- Create a new commit object with the current commit SHA as the parent and the new tree SHA, getting a commit SHA back
- Update the reference of your branch to point to the new commit SHA

Each of those steps has its own GitHub API query.